# My AutoHotKey script with #include won't run with batch file

Tags: batch-file, autohotkey

I have a folder full of AutoHotKey scripts.

On startup, I run a `.bat` file that is in the same directory as the scripts:

```
@echo off
for %%v in ("C:\Users\aparisi\Desktop\AHKScripts\*.ahk") do start "" "%%~v"
```

One of the scripts, which starts off with:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#include EscrowAgentContacts.ahk

+^a::
;;; script below, which works
```

doesn't run.  Instead, I get an error message saying the requested file can't be included, so the script will exit.

If I go back into the folder and manually click the script which wouldn't run, it runs fine.

I've tried putting a timeout in the batch file:

```
@echo off
for %%v in ("C:\Users\aparisi\Desktop\AHKScripts\*.ahk") do start timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK "" "%%~v"
```

but then none of the hotkeys work unless I go back and manually click all of them.

The script with the `#include` is lower down in the directory than the file being included.

Is there a way to make sure the file to be included is running prior to trying to start the script which does the including?

Comment: In any of the scripts you're running before this failing one, is the current directory and/or environment being modified and not returned to how it was afterwards?

Comment: No, none of the scripts modify the directory or environment.

Comment: What happens if you put a shortcut of your script in the Autorun folder? Does it start normally?

Comment: The AutoHotKey [#Include](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Include.htm) doc implies that the relative import directory is the working directory, which may not be the main script directory. View last line of *Remarks* section and the 2nd line of code in the *Examples* section. E.g. try `#Include %A_ScriptDir%` to set the include working directory for the following include lines or `#include %A_LineFile%\..\EscrowAgentContacts.ahk` to include the file from the script directory.